# More than one instance in an intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent

I was trying to understand the working of intents in android. According to the documentation, for an application to receive intent, it must pass all the three features in the filter. From the Google documentation:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
<!-- This activity is the main entry, should appear in app launcher -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
<!-- This activity handles "SEND" actions with text data -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
<!-- This activity also handles "SEND" and "SEND_MULTIPLE" with media data -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google.panorama360+jpg"/>
    <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
    <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

The share activity has 2 filters. Let say it didn't pass the first filter.The last intent filter has multiple actions and data types. What if an intent passes only some of the features of the filter and not all of them? Will it still work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The intent must pass any of the intent filters declared in the activity. To pass an intent filter, intent must match any action, any category and any data in a given intent filter. Read [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Resolution) for the details